# Jquery validation plugin is not working now in my code

Tags: jquery, validation

?Am using jquery validation plugin to validate my form as eveything is fine form is not working now,it used to work previously can any one tell me whats wrong in the code

here is my code

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery validation plug-in - main demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
//alert("Hi");
        </script>
        <script>
```

$().ready(function() {// alert("in ready");
            // validate the comment form when it is submitted

```
        $("#commentForm").validate({
            rules :{
                UMcustreceiptname:"required",
                UMcustemail:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
                UMname:"required",
                //   street:"required",
                //   city:"required",
                UMzip:{
                    required: true,
                    number:true,
                    minlength:4,
                    maxlength: 6
                },
                //                        UMcardtype: {
                //                            required: {
                //                                depends: function(element) {
                //                                    return $("#UMcardtype").val() == '';
                //                                }
                //                            }
                //                        },
                UMexpir:{
                    required: true,
                    number:true,
                    minlength:4,
                    maxlength: 4
                },
                //                          UMcvv2:{
                //                            required: true,
                //                            number:true,
                //                            minlength:3,
                //                            maxlength: 3
                //                        },
                UMcard: {
                    required: true,
                    number:true,
                    minlength:16,
                    maxlength:16


                }
            },
            messages: {
                cardtype: 'Please select a <b>card type</b>.'
            }



        });



    });
       </script>
<style type="text/css">
    #commentForm { width: 500px; }
    #commentForm label { width: 250px; }
    #commentForm label.error, #commentForm input.submit { margin-left: 253px; }
    #signupForm { width: 670px; }
    #signupForm label.error {
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: auto;
        display: inline;
    }
    #newsletter_topics label.error {
        display: none;
        margin-left: 103px;
    }
</style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="wowio_total" style="background-color:#fdf6f1;">
                <table width="700" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <h2 style="background-color:#f17122; width:500px; height:30px; line-height:30px; color:#FFFFFF;">PAYMENT GATEWAY</h2>
                            <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm"  action="http://www.domainname.com/index.php/bookInfo/pay"  method="POST" style="background-color:#faddcb; border:1px dotted #f17122;">
                                <input id="bookId" name="bookId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $bookId; ?>"/>
                                <input id="readerId" name="readerId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $readerId; ?>"/>

                                <input id="authorId" name="authorId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $authorId; ?>"/>
                                <input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/>
                                <fieldset style="border:1px solid #fbcfb3; ">
                                    <?php if (!empty($message)) { ?>
                                        <div class="err_msg">RESULT : <?php echo $message; ?></div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <p class="tbrcr">
                                        <label for="UMcustreceiptname" style="text-align:left; margin-left:27px;">Name :</label>
                                        <input id="UMcustreceiptname" name="UMcustreceiptname" value="" type="text" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:27px;">
                                        <label for="UMcustemail" style="text-align:left;">E-Mail :</label>
                                        <input id="UMcustemail" type="UMcustemail"  value="" name="UMcustemail" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:27px;">
                                        <label for="street" style="text-align:left;">Street :</label>
                                        <input id="street" type="text" name="street" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:36px;">
                                        <label for="city" style="text-align:left;">City :</label>
                                        <input id="city" type="text" name="city" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:10px;">
                                        <label for="UMzip" style="text-align:center;">Zip Code :</label>
                                        <input id="UMzip" type="text" name="UMzip" value="" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
<!--                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:5px;">
                                        <label for="UMcardtype" style="text-align:center;" >Card Type :</label>
                                        <select class="menu_br_card_type" id="UMcardtype" name="UMcardtype"  id="cardtype">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">..... Select One .....</option>
                                        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                                        <option value="mastercard">Master Card</option>
                                        <option value="amex">Amex</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>-->
                                    <p class="tbrcr" style="margin-left:-10px;">
                                        <label for="UMcard" style="text-align:left;">Card Number :</label>
                                        <input id="UMcard" name="UMcard" value="" type="text" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="tbrcr">
                                        <label for="UMexpir" style="text-align:center;">Expiry Date :</label>
                                        <input id="UMexpir" name="UMexpir" type="text"  value="" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>
                                   <!-- <p class="tbrcr">
                                        <label for="name" style="text-align:left; margin-left:27px;">Name on Card :</label>
                                        <input id="UMname" name="UMname"  type="text" class="tbrcr">
                                    </p>-->
                                    <p class="tbrcr">
                                        <label for="UMcvv2" style="text-align:left; margin-left:27px;">CVV2 :</label>
                                        <input id="UMcvv2" name="UMcvv2" value=""  type="text" class="tbrcr"/>
                                    </p>        

                                    <p class="tb_btn">
                                        <input class="submit" type="submit" id="submit"  value="Submit" class="tb_btn"/>
                                    </p>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any console errors????

Comment: no,it used to work fine not its not working

Comment: The URL `http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js` does not load.

Comment: Hey @sushmithasushu check `Manan` answer it's working properly.

Comment: Thanks Roland,replaced the file its working

Comment: Next time, try to include only the code necessary to reproduce the problem, not your whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSFiddle: http://goo.gl/rNDEHe. I have created your example and it's working.

Comment: Your answer should include the code that fixes the problem, or explain what you've done to fix it.